# mysql restoration process takes longer time

Tags: mysql, database

I have a Ubuntu 8.04 machine which has around 300 GB size `mysql` databases. I have dumped all the databases using the `mysqldump` command as below.

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > file.sql
```

Now, in the RHEL6 machine, I am trying to restore the `mysql` databases using:

```
mysql -u root -p < file.sql
```

However, the above command seems to take so much time and seems to execute forever. After 3 days when I check the restored database size, it shows just 30 GB as restored.

Is there an efficient way to restore the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before posting the answer, I would like to iterate that I asked my question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68966/mysql-database-restore-takes-long-time) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69587/mysql-restoration-suddenly-became-slow). As one might suggest, this question belongs in [*dba SE*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). But the reason I post it here is because it involves editing the configuration file in `/etc/my.cnf`.

**First Solution**

Edit the `/etc/my.cnf` to include the below parameters. The configuration file location might vary depending on the Linux distribution. In RHEL6, it is present under `/etc/my.cnf`.

```
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1
```

This suggestion was provided by [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert) and I would like to thank him for suggesting this solution.

***Testing***: Though, not as slow as the `mysql` command for restoration, this method still was taking considerable time. The command was executing for 3 days and had restored around 130 GB.

**Second Solution**

By setting a couple of flags before importing database dumps, we can dramatically speed up the restore process:

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

The above flags need to be set in the `.sql` file. Since we disabled auto-commit, we’ll also need to manually commit at the end of the restore:

```
COMMIT;
```

The above statement should be the last statement of the `.sql` file. Actually we can find a script to do the `mysqldump` from [here](http://loopj.com/2009/07/06/fast-mysql-backup-restore/).

I did not get a chance to test this solution but it makes a lot sense since it disables the foreign key checks.

Since we are restoring an entire database, we can speed things up by disabling unique checks and foreign key checks. Also, by committing everything at the end of the restore, rather than as the restore is in progress we get significant additional speed increases.

**Third Solution**

I have the entire `mysql` data directory backed up with me. The data directory is normally located under `/var/lib/mysql`. In my case, the data directory was mounted as a separate partition under `/mounts/mysql`. I had backed up the entire folder and so I restored the entire folder to the newer RHEL6 machine. Before restoring, we have to just make sure that the `mysqld` daemon is not started. Though, I restored using `rsync` command, I wanted to make sure that the file permissions are set currently in the new RHEL6 machine. So after restoring `/mounts/mysql` into the new RHEL6 system, I issued the below command.

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /mounts/mysql
```

Now, I tested the database and everything seemed perfectly cool. The restoration time was around 3 hours.

I have not seen people suggesting the above approach for `mysql` database restore anywhere. I see from [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69173/41588) answer that the `mysql` versions have to be compatible for restoring the databases from data directories. However, with my experience in the restoration so far, this is not true. As long as the permissions are correctly set, the databases work perfectly fine.

However, we need the `.sql` file when we try and restore a `mysql` database into a `sql-server` database or a `postgre` database.

Comment: The problem with backing up the datadir is that unless `mysqld` is stopped when you do so, the best outcome you can hope for is that the server where you restore to will attempt to recover from the crash it will believe occurred previously, because of the inevitable inconsistencies.  If the new server version is the same or newer, and the my.cnf is identical in a few important ways, then yes, this works.  We use a simiar process, when possible, for cloning replication slaves.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, good point. I had forgotten to mention that the `mysqld` daemon was stopped before the restoration. I will edit the answer to include that.